# Crontab not picking up new conjob

Tags: ubuntu, cron, docker, supervisord

When I build my server image, I write the following to a temporary file;

```
* * * * * php /var/www/artisan schedule:run
```

and then load it with

```
crontab < /tmp/cron
```

After deployment of the image, I run `cron -f` and I can see that the process is indeed running, but the cronjob is not being initiated.

If I run `crontab -e`, add a space, save it, run `crontab -e` again and remove the space, the cronjob working just fine **without reload of cron**.

I've tried reloading the cron on build with `/etc/init.d/cron reload`, but this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Does the file get created/updated in /var/spool/cron/crontabs? If so, check that the file ends in a newline; crontab entries aren't loaded if they don't end with a newline.

Comment: Yes, it is loaded and ends with a line break

Answer (score 0):

crontab needs to be notified. You can do something like this to (carefully!) append through the commandline or with a script:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * php /var/www/artisan schedule:run") | crontab -
```

The `2>/dev/null;` suppresses crontab's message when a user has an empty crontab.

Comment: That's basically what I already do, which does not work.

Comment: Sorry but no, that is not what you basically already do. Please look again at the example command I posted for you. It pipes through to `crontab -` so that crontab will be notified. Nothing in your first example, where you append, notifies crontab. In your second example, you invoke `crontab -e`, which notifies crontab. You need to notify crontab for it to pick up your job.

Comment: `crontab < /tmp/cron` notifies crontab